# PHP Way to generate and send to database a random number

Tags: php, database

I want to have a PHP page with a `Generate Key` button, when the users click it, it generates a random and unique number and sends it to a database.

Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: You can use uniqid: http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: You have to put "unique" in context. Unique in database, in time, ...?

Comment: **Here:** => https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20generate%20a%20random%20number%20in%20php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp <= that ought to get you started ;-)

Comment: Have you already tried to create the page to hold this button? Create a unique key using PHP? Connect or save any sort of data to a database? Your question comes across as "is PHP capable of creating a random string and communicating with a database?". Both of those questions demonstrate that you haven't even googled PHP in order to answer your question.

Comment: Please ask your question properly. Are you wanting to know how to generate a random number or write to a database or both?

Comment: I need to know how to do both.
Come on, I'm a newbie in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your button

```
<form method='post' action='generate.php'>
 <input type =submit>
</form>
```

Then on your php page...

```
$rand = rand(0,1000000000);

$sql = " insert into table (random) values ('$rand')";
Mysql_query($sql);
```

Note, im using mysql_* deprecated functions, use PDO instead....

But this is to just illustrate how to go about it

Comment: Wow, finally someone that understands i'm a newbie, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'sorry we\'re expierencing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('lr') or die($connect_error);
$fields = `rand_table`
$data = int rand ( int $min , int $max )
$inerting = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
?>
```